# C++ code for AVL tree gives access violation error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have written a code for avl which is giving me the below error after executing/mid way during execution.
I guess its some kind of memory leak issue. Can somebody point out what should be fixed ?
Codeblocks gave a popup segmentation error.
Error : `Unhandled exception at 0x77B2A710 (ntdll.dll) in ADS Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014.`

Code:

```
{
InputGenerator ip;
int numbers[1000000];
ip.RandomInput(numbers, 1000000);
AVL *avlTree = (AVL *) malloc(1000000* sizeof(AVL *));
AVL *root = NULL;


auto avlOps = make_shared < AVL > ();
int input = 0;
*avlTree = AVL(numbers[0]);
root = avlTree;
avlTree++;

int balanceFac = 0;
input = 1;
while (input != 1000000)
{

    //cout << "sorting : ";
    //avlOps->InorderPrint(root);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Inserting : " << numbers[input] << endl;

    *avlTree = AVL(numbers[input]);
    avlOps->Insert(avlTree, root);

    // check if rotation is required.
    AVL * tempNo=avlTree->GetParent();  

    while(tempNo!=NULL)
    {
        int balFac=0;
        AVL* node1=NULL;
        AVL* node2=NULL;
        AVL* node3=NULL;
        int rCase=0;
        balFac=avlOps->GetBalanceFactor(tempNo);
        if(balFac>1||balFac<-1)
        {
            node1=tempNo;
            if(balFac>0)
            {
                node2=node1->GetLChild();
                balFac=avlOps->GetBalanceFactor(node2);
                if(balFac>0)
                {
                    node3=node2->GetLChild();
                    rCase=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    node3=node2->GetRChild();
                    rCase=3;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                node2=node1->GetRChild();

                balFac=avlOps->GetBalanceFactor(node2);
                if(balFac>0)
                {
                    node3=node2->GetLChild();
                    rCase=4;
                }
                else
                {
                    node3=node2->GetRChild();
                    rCase=2;
                }
            }
            root=avlOps->Rotation(node1,node2,node3,root,rCase);
        }
        tempNo=tempNo->GetParent();
    }
    cout<<endl;


    cout << "Root :" << root->GetKey() << endl;
    cout << "******" << endl;
    avlTree++;
    input++;

}

avlOps->InorderPrint(root);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: it just leads me to chkstk.asm I am new to c++ so cant make out much of the file , and i cant really step into the code

Comment: So you are using a debugger? In that case, have it output the contents of the call stack when the error has occurred. That should tell you what line in your code caused the immediate error. (The actual problem may be somewhere else, but it will still help find out what's going wrong.)

Comment: how do i print the output of call stack ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue I could see is:

```
AVL *avlTree = (AVL *) malloc(1000000* sizeof(AVL *));
```

should be

```
AVL *avlTree = (AVL *) malloc(1000000* sizeof(AVL));
                                              ^^^
```

There might be more. A debugger is your best friend in situations like this.

Comment: I am still not able to to get it to work for 1,000,000 numbers it just exits immediatly with the erro Unhandled exception at 0x003228F7 in ADS Project.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x01002000).

Comment: found out the issue , was hitting max array size